# How to type # in vim with a British keyboard layout on OS X

Tags: mac, vim, localization

My Mac has a British keyboard layout and the `#` symbol is entered with option-3, instead of shift-3 as with the US layout. This arrangement, though odd, works fine most of the time. However, when trying to edit a file with vim in a terminal, typing option-3 just takes vim out of edit mode.

I use `#` often for comments in scripting languages and for pre-processor directives in C.

How do I type `#`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option: <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd>, <kbd>Shift-N</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd>

Comment: Yes. That works.

Comment: I have a mac with UK keyboard too, but ctrl and K gives me ? Shift-N and N and not sure what 'b; means

Comment: @rtacconi "?" means that Vim is waiting for you to type the next two characters of the digraph, "Nb" in this case. `:help digraph` .

Comment: after realising that I typically do not need neither £ nor € I removed british input and added U.S. and the life is great again

Answer (score 4):

In Terminal's settings, un-check 'Use option as meta key'. It's under the 'Settings' tab's 'Keyboard' pane.

Comment: In iTerm, this setting can be found under Preferences > Profiles > [your profile name] > Keys > General > Left Option key > Normal

Answer (score 0):

Does <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>, <kbd>Option-3</kbd> work?

Comment: No. I just get ^[3 ("\x1b3").

Answer (score 0):

You should use \ or | for # in case you have british keyboard. It works for me.